# Syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Pragmatic Agile Web Development with Rails book. This is my controller:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @handy_men = HandyMan.order(:firstname)
  end
end
```

I'm struggling with this error:

```
store_controller.rb:3: Syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

Could you help me to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Is that the full `store_controller.rb` file? Is the third line `@handy_men...`? Because that should execute without any problems if so; there are no errors in the code you posted.

Comment: Yes this is all, and as you said it must not be an error, I did exactly as the book said and I got this .

Comment: Cut and paste store_controller, the whole file not just an extract, error might be coming from somewhere else

Comment: class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @handy_men = HandyMan.order(:firstname)  
  end
end

Comment: @OussamaGHOUAGH I don't know why someone has down-voted your question, but if you have a syntax error like that we should be able to help you fix it. Right now we don't see any error in the code you've posted. Have you got the project in a Git repository or something like that? If so please post the link to the repository.

Comment: For real people wanna downvote this question!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I think what the problem may actually be is that the ruby file above contains some sort of invisible white space, can I ask what editor you're using?

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi , Yes I hope so and  Thank you for your support this is where my project is loaded. https://bitbucket.org/OussamaGHOUAGH/handybee

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3 @mrageh

Answer (score 1):

@OussamaGHOUAGH You've probably got some sort of weird character in the above file (probably a non ASCII character like an invisible white space character). So when you get errors like the one above, it means the parser does not recognise a token provided by the lexer.

In short you've probably got some weird character inserted in the above file and that can happen if you're using a editor that inserts the character or if you copied and pasted the above code from an ebook. The best thing to do is rewrite all of the code in the above file and see if you get the same error again.

Checkout the tweet and Gist by Gary Bernhardt
https://twitter.com/garybernhardt/status/623973427695632384
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/garybernhardt/5cd9c63d8084c93c74c5/raw/62d68b02d0807471779c6002c1efc11227ce590a/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrageh, when I opened the file with TextMate I realized the existence of a "." in the end of the only instruction I have.

Comment: @OussamaGHOUAGH if this answer helped you can you please upvote it ;)

Comment: I ve tried @mrageh, but I need more reputation to do that.